# Process running under and id that has **Never logged in**

Tags: security, users, ps

I have an account which has never been logged in, but `ps` shows stuff running under that account:

[image]

How is this possible? What could be the above apps that are running? Has my machine been hacked?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead. Have you checked the system logs for e.g., entries from ssh about this user? Is it possible they're doing `ssh <host> some-command`, which IIRC might not show an entry in `lastlog`?

Comment: Some root process may have done `su - frank`. Why is the user `frank` defined on your system? When and why the file `go` was created in `frank`'s home directory?

Comment: I created the account `frank` for a user, but he hasn't logged in yet. There are no files in its home directory other than those created by the account creation process.